# Angular - Sporadically failing Unit Tests (Router)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, web-frontend

I have an Angular 8 Application which uses the router to switch between some main components.
Now i've done some unit tests and sometimes the tests are all passing, but sometimes one or two are failing - always with the same reason.

This is the output i get by running ng test (when tests are failing):

```
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 32 of 34 ERROR (0 secs / 0.819 secs)
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'overview'
  Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'overview'
      at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.js:4295:1)
      at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.js:4259:1)
      at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/operators/catchError.js:29:1)
      at MapSubscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:75:1)
      at MapSubscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:55:1)
      at MapSubscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:75:1)
      at MapSubscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:55:1)
      at MapSubscriber._error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:75:1)
      at MapSubscriber.error (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:55:1)
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 34 of 34 ERROR (1.167 secs / 0.907 secs)
```

I've included the ***RouterTestingModule*** in the imports array of every test file, where the according component uses the router in any way.
Like this for example:

```
describe('FeedbackComponent', () => {
  let component: FeedbackComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FeedbackComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FeedbackComponent, OverviewHeaderComponent ],
      imports: [FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FeedbackComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Anyone who ever had this kind of problems? Or knows why this is randomly failing?
Thank you very much in advance already :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
        [{path: 'overview', component: FeedbackComponent}]
      )
```

Really, `FeedbackComponent` can be any dummy component you create. This might fix your issue but I am not sure how it will scale. It seems you have a larger underlying issue. I see the error was thrown in the `afterAll`, do you have any of `afterAll` hooks? Any funny business in them?

Comment: So, karma just needs to find any kind of component under the routes i am using in the tested component?  I haven't got any afterAll hooks in my project.

Comment: Try this to see if the error will go away. It will be annoying adding it to every test. But most likely you have a deeper issue somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems you're right there has to be some deeper issues going on there. If i can find an answer i will post it here :)